# Jupyter notebook comment shortcut is not working

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I was trying to comment lines in jupyter notebook using "ctrl+/". But it's not working.

I'm using windows 10 and mozilla firefox.

Comment: I don't get the point to have this question downvoted, since it is a very common problem. I have windows 10 too and I am not able to let the shortcut work

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. Did you find a way to fix it?

Comment: Nope, Unfortunately not. You might reset and clean up the settings.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is probably because of your browser settings. ctrl+/ must be set to something else or you are not in edit mode.

Comment: Are you using Vimium extension? I read on another thread that it was the source of the problem

Comment: No, I ain't using vimium extension. I'm trying to solve it. But couldn't find any possibility .

Here is something "https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/1901"

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem, when I'd switched browser to edge and then switch ed back to chrome. The browser's shortcut settings is the problem. To solve this go to settings in chrome browser-> Reset and clean up-> Restore settings to their original defaults -> restore settings