# Comment with ctrl - / jupyter notebook not working on Linux Mozilla Fire Fox

Tags: linux, firefox, jupyter-notebook, comments

Comment in jupyter notebook with ctrl-/ does not work on my Linux server using Mozilla Firefox
However it is defined like that.
Is there a way to fix this or change the shortcut? (The Edit Keyboard Shortcuts menue doese not show comment)

I found several issues on that, but no answer.

BR

Links:
https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/1901

[Jupyter notebook comment shortcut is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55147319/jupyter-notebook-comment-shortcut-is-not-working)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After internet research i found out that one has to press: cmd + /, but the / has to be from the numpad!

I still do not know why and how to change it, but at least I can now, comment blocks.

BR, maths

Comment: Imagine having no numblock (lots of laptops don't). This inconsistencies between browsers, keymaps,... are part of the reason that moving from well-aged IDEs and editors to recreating the whole editing experience in a web app seems unwise.